# Update a database according to the month and year via App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am in the process of setting up indicators for a staff monitoring from [a Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1isKePRMntSa3faDBeSC1xcWXfGRpUURbWhwmup5j0-4/edit?usp=sharing).
The list of all the staff allows me to retrieve in the tab "Monthly transition indicators" the number of people who are not present in training, on their first day of work, who quit before the end of their mission, who go to the end of their mission or whose data has not been entered. I also indicated the current date (with recovery of the month and year).

In a second tab, "Monthly indicators", I reformat the data to be able to use them later with Data Studio.

I have a script that counts the number of lines in this tab. If the month, the year and the label (present in column C in both tabs) are identical, then the data in the "Monthly indicators" tab are updated.

However, if the month and/or the year do not match, then a new line must be created and the corresponding data entered.

And it is for this part that I have a problem. Indeed, since my for loop starts from 0 to reach the number of rows present in the tab, this is not a problem when I simulate for the month of February since only the month of January is present. On the other hand, if January and February are present and I simulate a record for the month of March, then it notes me the data twice. This is normal since there is twice as much data and therefore the March data is repeated twice.

Here is my code:

```
function majDonnees() {
   // Déclaration des constantes
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuilleProvisoire = classeur.getSheetByName("Indicateurs mensuels transition");
   const feuilleBDD = classeur.getSheetByName("Indicateurs Mensuels");

   // Récupération du mois et de l'année
   var moisDuJour = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("B2").getValue();
   var anneeDuJour = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("B3").getValue();

   // Contrôle si le mois en cours est saisi dans la base de données
   var tBDD = feuilleBDD.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
   var nbRows = tBDD.filter(String).length;

   // ----- GESTION ÉCART MENSUEL ----- //
   // Récupération des libellés de l'onglet provisoire
   var libNonPresentHS = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C2").getValue();
   var libNonPresentPremierJ = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C3").getValue();
   var libMissionNonTerminee = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C4").getValue();
   var libMissionEnCours = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C5").getValue();
   var libDonneeNonRemplie = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C6").getValue();

   // Récupération des valeurs de l'onglet provisoire
   var nonPresentHS = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D2").getValue();
   var nonPresentPremierJ = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D3").getValue();
   var missionNonTerminee = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D4").getValue();
   var missionEnCours = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D5").getValue();
   var donneeNonRemplie = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D6").getValue();


   for (let i = 0; i < nbRows; i ++){
     // Récupération du mois et de l'année
     var moisBDD = feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(i+2)).getValue();
     var anneeBDD = feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(i+2)).getValue();
     var libelleBDD = feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(i+2)).getValue();
     // Écriture du résultat pour "Non présents à la formation HS"
     if (libelleBDD == libNonPresentHS){
       if (moisDuJour == moisBDD && anneeDuJour == anneeBDD){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(nonPresentHS);
       } 
       else {
         feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(moisDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(libNonPresentHS);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(nonPresentHS);
       }
     }
     // Écriture du résultat pour "Non présents le premier jour de travail"
     else if (libelleBDD == libNonPresentPremierJ){
       if (moisDuJour == moisBDD && anneeDuJour == anneeBDD){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(nonPresentPremierJ);
       }
       else {
         feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(moisDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(libNonPresentPremierJ);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(nonPresentPremierJ);
       }
     }
     // Écriture du résultat pour "Missions avortées"
     else if (libelleBDD == libMissionNonTerminee){
       if (moisDuJour == moisBDD && anneeDuJour == anneeBDD){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(missionNonTerminee);
       }
       else {
         feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(moisDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(libMissionNonTerminee);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(missionNonTerminee);
       }
     }
     // Écriture du résultat pour "Missions en cours ou terminées"
     else if (libelleBDD == libMissionEnCours){
       if (moisDuJour == moisBDD && anneeDuJour == anneeBDD){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(missionEnCours);
       }
       else {
         feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(moisDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(libMissionEnCours);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(missionEnCours);
       }
     }
     // Écriture du résultat pour "Données non remplies par la production"
     else if (libelleBDD == libDonneeNonRemplie){
       if (moisDuJour == moisBDD && anneeDuJour == anneeBDD){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(donneeNonRemplie);
       }
       else {
         feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(moisDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(libDonneeNonRemplie);
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+i)).setValue(donneeNonRemplie);
       }
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are encountering? From your explanation and in particular the paragraph before the code, I could not find the issue you have.

Comment: I made a mistake in my explanation.
Since my for loop starts from 0 to reach the number of rows present in the tab, when I add the month of February the first time, it is not a problem. But if I update it, it adds more rows for the month of February.
What I would like is that if the month already exists, the data updates when the script runs. On the other hand, if the month does not exist, the data is added to the database afterwards.

Comment: Your English seems fine. Note that there is a general agreement here that commentary about a writer's English, or whether a writer's question is clear, or other similar remarks, are best omitted from questions. Brevity and technical writing is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my problem. I added flags to define the states and added a loop to add the data if the month doesn't match. It's possible that there is a simpler solution but I haven't found it.

Here is the code:

```
function majDonnees() {
   // Déclaration des constantes
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuilleProvisoire = classeur.getSheetByName("Indicateurs mensuels transition");
   const feuilleBDD = classeur.getSheetByName("Indicateurs Mensuels");

   // Récupération du mois et de l'année
   var moisDuJour = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("B2").getValue();
   var anneeDuJour = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("B3").getValue();

   // Contrôle si le mois en cours est saisi dans la base de données
   var tBDD = feuilleBDD.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
   var nbRows = tBDD.filter(String).length;

   // ----- GESTION ÉCART MENSUEL ----- //
   // Récupération des libellés de l'onglet provisoire
   var libNonPresentHS = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C2").getValue();
   var libNonPresentPremierJ = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C3").getValue();
   var libMissionNonTerminee = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C4").getValue();
   var libMissionEnCours = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C5").getValue();
   var libDonneeNonRemplie = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("C6").getValue();

   // Récupération des valeurs de l'onglet provisoire
   var nonPresentHS = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D2").getValue();
   var nonPresentPremierJ = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D3").getValue();
   var missionNonTerminee = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D4").getValue();
   var missionEnCours = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D5").getValue();
   var donneeNonRemplie = feuilleProvisoire.getRange("D6").getValue();

   // Création des flags
   var fNonPresentHS = false;
   var fNonPresent1erJour = false;
   var fMissionNonTerminee= false;
   var fMissionEnCours = false;
   var fDonneeNonRemplie = false;

   // Pour une mise à jour de données existantes
   for (let i = 0; i < nbRows; i ++){
     // Récupération du mois et de l'année
     var moisBDD = feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(i+2)).getValue();
     var anneeBDD = feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(i+2)).getValue();
     var libelleBDD = feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(i+2)).getValue();
     if (moisDuJour == moisBDD && anneeDuJour == anneeBDD){
       // Écriture du résultat pour "Non présents à la formation HS"
       if (libelleBDD == libNonPresentHS){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(nonPresentHS);
         fNonPresentHS = true;
       } 
       // Écriture du résultat pour "Non présents le premier jour de travail"
       else if (libelleBDD == libNonPresentPremierJ){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(nonPresentPremierJ);
         fNonPresent1erJour = true;
       }
       // Écriture du résultat pour "Missions avortées"
       else if (libelleBDD == libMissionNonTerminee){
           feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(missionNonTerminee);
           fMissionNonTerminee = true;
       }
       // Écriture du résultat pour "Missions en cours ou terminées"
       else if (libelleBDD == libMissionEnCours){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(missionEnCours);
         fMissionEnCours = true;
      }
       // Écriture du résultat pour "Données non remplies par la production"
       else if (libelleBDD == libDonneeNonRemplie){
         feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(2+i)).setValue(donneeNonRemplie);
         fDonneeNonRemplie = true;
       }
     }
   }
   for (let j = 0; j < nbRows ; j ++){
     if (fNonPresentHS == false){
       feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(moisDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(libNonPresentHS);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(nonPresentHS);
       fNonPresentHS = true;
     }
     else if (fNonPresent1erJour == false){
       feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(moisDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(libNonPresentPremierJ);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(nonPresentPremierJ);
       fNonPresent1erJour = true;
     }
     else if (fMissionNonTerminee == false){
       feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(moisDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(libMissionNonTerminee);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(missionNonTerminee);
       fMissionNonTerminee = true;
     }
     else if (fMissionEnCours == false){
       feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(moisDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(libMissionEnCours);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(missionEnCours);
       fMissionEnCours = true;
     }
     else if (fDonneeNonRemplie == false){
       feuilleBDD.getRange("A"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(moisDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("B"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(anneeDuJour);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("C"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(libDonneeNonRemplie);
       feuilleBDD.getRange("D"+(nbRows+2+j)).setValue(donneeNonRemplie);
       fDonneeNonRemplie = true;
     }
   }
 }
```